# Passing a response file to a process in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a process that would traditionally be run like so (in the command line):

filepath.exe @"respfile.resp"

where respfile.resp is a response file that has command line arguments for the executable.

Running the command like that works as desired in the command prompt.

However I am trying to use a powershell script to run multiple programs. Here is what I have:

```
if (Test-Path $respPath){
        $executionResposne = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru -FilePath  $bimlcExePath -ArgumentList $respPath
        if ($executionResposne.ExitCode -eq 1){
            Write-Output "Unable to successfully run the process. Exiting program."
            return
        }
    }
```

and I am getting the following error message:

```
Error:: filepath\to\resp\file Data at the root level is invalid.
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed the quotes for the interpreter:

```
-ArgumentList "@`"$respPath`""
```